# What is a vectoid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, terminology, definition

I've seen the notion of a "vectoid" thrown around a bunch of times, being something similar to a ringoid, a groupoid, etc. For instance, there's [a definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebrad) here. However, it's pretty difficult for me to parse this definition, so I am looking for an axiomatic definition for a vectoid which isn't dependent on a ton of heavy duty category theory background to grasp.

I would imagine that a "vectoid" is similar to a "groupoid," a "ringoid," etc, except now it's basically a "vector space with multiple objects." Is that the right idea?

Can someone present a purely algebraic axiomatic definition of a vectoid, similar to the axiomatic definition for a vector space?

EDIT: originally I quoted the book "Computer Arithmetic and Validity" as having a definition closer to something like a "moduleoid", e.g. a groupoid with a "ringoid of scalars." However, it seems this book may not be using the same "vectoid" definition as above. Does there exist a shared or unified meaning for this term?

Comment: According to the nLab link, "A vectoid is a finitely complete and cocomplete category $C$ with a small set of generators, where all epimorphisms are universally effective and where the following “completeness/totality” axiom holds: every functor $F:C^\mathrm{op} \to \mathrm{Set}$ commuting with all colimits is representable."  If you want that written out in axioms, it'll be about 5 pages long.

Comment: The textbook "Computer Arithmetic and Validity" that I'm reading has it as about six axioms.

Comment: If it's the same meaning of vectoid, that would be shocking.

Comment: Well, that's partly why I asked the question! This texbook basically seems to define it as an "abelian groupoid with a ringoid of scalars." I'm not quite sure if I'm interpreting this definition correctly though or if it's even the same vectoid.

Comment: That does not sound like the same thing.

Comment: It looks like it may not be, so I've clarified to even ask if a "Vectoid" has one meaning at all.

Comment: No, it does not have just one meaning. The definition on the nLab and the definition you mention are totally unrelated. (Groupoids don't have limits and colimits, for instance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responding to the clarified question in the comments: No, it does not have just one meaning. The definition on the nLab and the definition you mention are totally unrelated. (Groupoids don't have limits and colimits, for instance.) Your book is trying to give some kind of notion of a not-necessarily-associative "vector space", whereas the nLab is categorifying the category of vector spaces.

Comment: I think the book I was using is going with the other definition of "groupoid" and "ringoid," e.g. the associative versions of those things, so a vectoid is something similar. Does there exist a name for the horizontal categorification of a vector space?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia The alleged "other" definition of a groupoid, though it's beyond me that anybody could be caught using it in this century, is "a magma", which is not associative. It's not obvious to me that "a vector space" is really susceptible to horizontal categorification in the typical sense; it seems similar to asking for the horizontal categorification of a set, and I don't really know what that would be.

Comment: Sorry, typo in my post, I meant "non-associative" versions of those things, meaning this: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ringoid.html -- how would this be similar to categorifying a set?

Comment: @MikeBattaglia Just insofar as a set is to a vector space as a monoid is to an algebra. It’s the latter that have obvious horizontal categorifications.